# Need help to understand the irony in the paragraphs

Tags: meaning

[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

I do not understand the irony mentioned at the end of the second paragraph. Could anybody help me?

My understanding is that the composers need to stay focused to create songs that makes people focus. Is this an irony? Or if my understanding is correct, do you think that it is a good irony?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  Take your time and retype the words.  Then link to the source.  Images make life hard for screen readers and they aren't indexed or searchable.

Comment: -1 for the image of text. See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/91457 There are also online OCR apps available.

Comment: Also, who wrote the text and where was it published? Quoted sources or texts should be properly attributed.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the irony is that the composers must (according to the author) focus to create music that the players will not focus on too much, because it would be distracting from the game if the players focused on the music.